# AWS lambda javascript IAM Role

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

According to the AWS Lambda documentation, a Lambda function written in Node will use the credentials of the IAM role assigned to the function. The same is true for functions written in Python. I wrote a function in Node, and it is getting an unauthorized error. The same function in Python, using the same configuration, works. I am using the official AWS SDK in both cases.

The fact that it works in Python and not in Node tells me that it is not a configuration issue. If hard code credentials into the Node function, it works, so I know the function logic works.

Any ideas?

Code that is now working (but did not yesterday!)

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');



exports.handler = async (event) => {
        const EC2 = new AWS.EC2();
        var instanceId = "i-xxxxxxxxxxx";
        var params = {
            InstanceIds: [instanceId], 
            DryRun: false
        };
        var response = {
            status: 200
        };
        try {
            const startInstance = await EC2.startInstances(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error: " + err.code);
                    response.status = 403;
                    response.error = err.code;
                } else if (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    response.instanceInfo = data;
                }
            }).promise();
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err.code);
        }
        return response;
};
```

Comment: Please post the code for both functions. The runtime of the function doesn't relate to the IAM role it uses, it's most likely an issue in your Nodejs code

Comment: Well, now it is working.

Comment: Suggest you delete the question, or otherwise close it, to save others some time.

Comment: Did you, at some point, find that your IAM role needed its permissions edited?  Anecdotally, changes to the permissions attached to the IAM role used by a Lambda function may take some time to propagate, if you update the permissions after running the function for the first time.  I had a similar situation occur one night while developing a new Lambda function. I would have pulled my hair out, if I had any to spare.  The next day, after I mustered up the energy to take a other look at it... it "just started working," because the updated role policy had been correct all along.